# return fixed size array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, clang

Sometimes I want to return an array of something, I know what I should do it let the caller to make the array and modify the array in the method. But it turns out this works?

```
@interface Test : NSObject
@end

@implementation Test

- (CGPoint[2])test {
    CGPoint p1 = {1, 2};
    CGPoint p2 = {3, 4};
    return (CGPoint[2]) {p1, p2};
}

- (int[2])test2 {
    int i = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    return (int[2]){i, i2};
}

- (int[5])test3 {
    int i = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    return (int[5]){i, i2, 3, 4, 5};
}

@end

@implementation testTests

- (void)testExample
{
    Test *t = [Test new];
    CGPoint p = [t test][0];
    CGPoint p2 = [t test][1];
    CGPoint *ps = [t test];
    CGPoint p3 = ps[0];
    CGPoint p4 = ps[1];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p), NSStringFromCGPoint(p2), NSStringFromCGPoint(p3), NSStringFromCGPoint(p4));
    // {1, 2} {3, 4} {1, 2} {3, 4}

    {
        Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([Test class], @selector(test));
        const char *rettype = method_copyReturnType(m);
        NSUInteger size = 0;
        NSGetSizeAndAlignment(rettype, &size, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%s %d", rettype, size); // [2{CGPoint=ff}] 16
    }

    {
        Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([Test class], @selector(test2));
        const char *rettype = method_copyReturnType(m);
        NSUInteger size = 0;
        NSGetSizeAndAlignment(rettype, &size, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%s %d", rettype, size); // [2i] 8
    }

    {
        Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([Test class], @selector(test3));
        const char *rettype = method_copyReturnType(m);
        NSUInteger size = 0;
        NSGetSizeAndAlignment(rettype, &size, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%s %d", rettype, size); // [5i] 20
    }
}

@end
```

So it looks like I can return an array of something directly like return a struct. As `NSGetSizeAndAlignment` suggested, the return value is actually the whole array not just a pointer. (16 for `CGPoint[2]`, 8 for `int[2]`, 20 for `int[5]`)

But to actually use the returned value, I can only do this

```
CGPoint *ps = [t test];
```

and here `ps` is just a pointer. So the question is that can I safely return array like this? where is the array allocated at? In stack of callee function or in stack of caller function? Is true that whole array is copied from callee function or like struct the complier allocated the array in caller function automatically?

I am using Xcode 4.6.2

---

**Update**

Looks like this only woks for 32bits app, which includes iOS app (ARM), iOS simulator (x86) and 32bits OSX app.

Comment: Please condense the code so it just shows your problem. Don't expect people to wade through tens of lines in search for a basic question like this.

Comment: @meaning-matters my problem is can I do `CGPoint *ps = [t test];`, is it not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support returning an array. Why this apparently works for you I've no idea. I entered your code, added the missing methods/imports, fixed the format warnings, tweaked the first `NSLog` - none of which changes the code in any significant way - and the result is:

```
p: {0.000000, 0.000000}
p2: {49923903424063506281151950574939686583391145211556805465272890158614887709849874883833083042335634395057539888815696938380880844447770099086084465717389090095104.000000, 5053651901346670085892443969395884608467030378650281488576308318306304.000000}
p3: {0.000000, 0.000000}
p4: {0.000000, 0.000000}
```

In short, garbage - which is what you'd expect.

That is with Xcode 4.6.2 on 10.8.4 using the Apple LLVM default compiler. Switch to the gcc-llvm compiler and it won't even compile - the error is methods cannot return arrays. For completeness also tested the C11 language options (Apple LLVM) - runs and produces garbage as above.

If you really need to pass arrays by value you can do this using a simple trick: primitive types (int, float, etc.) and *structures* are all passed by valued in C, so you can pass an array by value by wrapping it in a `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
   CGPoint values[2];
} Array2;

@interface Test2 : NSObject
@end

@implementation Test2

- (Array2)test
{
   CGPoint p1 = {1, 2};
   CGPoint p2 = {3, 4};
   return (Array2) {{p1, p2}};
}


- (void)testExample
{
   Test2 *t = self;
   CGPoint p = [t test].values[0];
   CGPoint p2 = [t test].values[1];
   Array2 ps = [t test];
   CGPoint p3 = ps.values[0];
   CGPoint p4 = ps.values[1];
   NSLog(@"p: %@\np2: %@\np3: %@\np4: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p), NSStringFromCGPoint(p2), NSStringFromCGPoint(p3), NSStringFromCGPoint(p4));
}

@end
```

and this produces:

```
p: {1.000000, 2.000000}
p2: {3.000000, 4.000000}
p3: {1.000000, 2.000000}
p4: {3.000000, 4.000000}
```

as it should.

**Addendum - Response to Comment**

The C Standard disallows the returning of arrays (and functions) - but references to arrays (and functions) are allowed.

For function parameters if the type given is an array (or function) type then it is adjusted to mean reference to array (or function).

Though I don't know that the Standard states it, some compilers (e.g. Apple 4.2, but not GCC 4.2) apply the parameter type adjustment to the return type as well - so you can declare a function to return an array and it is adjusted to be a reference to an array.

Objective-C's metadata is recording the *declared*, rather than the *adjusted*, type. This is why you see the results you do when calling `method_copyReturnType`/`NSGetSizeAndAlignment`. However the compiling is following the standard, adjusting the type, and not returning arrays by value.

Having said that a compiler could of course choose to implement array-by-value as an extension - as the machinery to do so needs to be there to support struct-by-value anyway. I don't know offhand whether any compiler supports such an extension. I have only tested the 4.2 Intel compilers (Apple & GCC) and they do not (and GCC does not support declaring the return type as an array either, that is a compile time error).

HTH

Comment: what return type do you get from `method_copyReturnType` and what is the size?

Comment: Why it works is probably because the pointer which holds the array is still pointing to (now invalid) memory. It's undefined behavior, but that doesn't mean it has to crash.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I have check the assemble code generated and found it use `objc_msgSend_stret` to call the method. so the return type is not just a pointer. And yes I cannot do anything similar in pure C/C++ code so I think this is something ObjC only.

Comment: @CRD so you are saying `method_copyReturnType` is lying? metadata may not match to what is actually happening? I will test my code using different compiler settings when I have time.

Comment: @xlc - it is not that `method_copyReturnType` is lying, it is what that type means in the context it is in. The Standard allows you to declare a parameter as an array type but its meaning semantically is a reference to an array. You need to interpret the result of `method_copyReturnType` based on the context. Yes, its a little messy, but's that C for you ;-)

Comment: @xlc - targeting Intel the compiler does not use `objc_msgSend_stret` (it does do that for the struct-wrapped array version I showed). If you are targeting ARM then maybe the compiler is doing that, but if so its an undocumented extension - as I said above any compiler could implement such an extension quite easily. It seems a bit strange though to implement such an extension on ARM only.

Comment: just tried with different settings, for 32bits binary, both llvm and llvm-gcc woks. but not working for 64bits binary.