# How to return a C-style array of integers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c

How to return a C-style array of integers from an Objective-C method? This is what my code looks like so far:

Function call:

```
maze = [amaze getMaze];
```

Function:

```
-(int*) getMaze{
    return maze;
}
```

I just started writing in Objective-C today so this is all new to me.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you gave?

Comment: It's not returning the array.

Comment: What is `maze`, and where do you set it and access it from?

Comment: Did you allocate and initialize the array?

Comment: is this your code?  `(int*) getMaze{}` is not the function prototype. It should be `(int*) getMaze(){}`

Comment: @syler: That would be a C function, whereas he is writing an Objective-C method. At any rate, it is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarafication everyone, I ended up just converting it to a NSArray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C if you need to return an array from a function, you need to allocate memory for it using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and then return the pointer pointing to the newly allocated memory.

Once you're done working with this memory you need to [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) it.

Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* need this include at top for malloc and free */

int* foo(int size)
{
    int* out = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); /* need to get the size of the int type and multiply it 
                                            * by the number of integers we would like to return */

    return out; /* returning pointer to the function calling foo(). 
                 * Don't forget to free the memory allocated with malloc */
}

int main()
{
    ... /* some code here */

    int* int_ptr = foo(25); /* int_ptr now points to the memory allocated in foo */

    ... /* some more code */

    free(int_ptr); /* we're done with this, let's free it */

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

This is as C style as it gets :) There are probably other (arguably more suitable) ways to do this in Objective C. However, as Objective C is considered a strict superset of C, this would also work.

If I may further expand on the need to do this by pointers. C-style arrays allocated in a function are considered [local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269627/c-local-array-definition-versus-a-malloc-call), once the function is out of scope they are automatically cleaned up.

As pointed out by another poster, returning a standard array (e.g. `int arr[10];`) from a function is a bad idea as by the time the array is returned it no longer exists.

In C we get around this problem by allocating memory dynamically using `malloc` and having a pointer that points to that memory returned.

However unless you free this memory adequately, you may introduce a memory leak or some other nasty behavior (e.g. `free`-ing a `malloc`-ed pointer twice will produce [unwanted results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039440/is-there-any-harm-in-calling-free-for-the-same-pointer-twice-in-a-c-program)).

Comment: this is very likely to intoduce memory leak and we want to avoid manual memory management as much as possible

Comment: Agreed, I've hopefully made it clear that this is C only and that Objective C probably has better ways of doing this :)

Answer (score 4):

*Given you explicitly ask about C-style arrays no suggestions here that you should use `NSArray` etc.*

You *cannot* return a C-style array directly (see below) as a value in Objective-C (or C or C++), you *can* return a reference to such an array.

Types such as `int`, `double` and `struct x` can all be *passed by value* - that is the actual bits representing the value are passed around. Other things; such as C-style arrays, dynamically allocated memory, Objective-C style objects, etc.; are all *passed by reference* - that is a reference to a location in memory that contains the actual bits the represent the value is passed around.

So to return a C-style array from a function/method you can:

1. Dynamically (`malloc` *et al*) an array and return the reference to the allocated memory;
2. Pass *in* a reference to an already existing array and have the function fill it up; or
3. Wrap the array up as a `struct`...

The normal choices are (1) or (2) - note you cannot return a reference to a stack allocated array, as in:

```
int *thisIsInvalid()
{
   int myValues[5];
   ...
   return myValues; // will not work, the type is correct but once function
                    // returns myValues no longer exists.
}
```

If you really want to return a (small) array by value you can actually do it using (3). Remember that `struct` values are passed by value. So the following will work:

```
typedef struct
{
   int array[5];
} fiveInts;

fiveInts thisIsValid()
{
   fiveInts myValues;
   ...
   myValues.array[3] = ...; // etc.
   ...
   return myValues;
}
```

(Note that there is no overhead from wrapping the array inside a `struct` when it comes to reading/writing the array - the cost in the above is copying all the values back - hence only advised for small arrays!)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSArray *)toArray:(int *)maze {
   NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int c = 0; maze[c] != NULL; c++) {
      [retVal addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maze[c]]];
   }
   return [retVal array];
}
```

I've never been comfortable passing mutable data in and out of methods and not sure why. If you need to change the values later, send the array a `mutableCopy` message.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in this way

```
- (void)getArray:(int *)array withLength:(NSUInteger)length{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = i;
}

int array[3];
[object getArray:array withLength:3];
NSLog(@"%d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[2]);  // 1 2 3
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first code example is bugged. You can't return an array, because it decays into a pointer into the stack frame that's about to get popped.

Comment: @Chuck No you are wrong. I have checked the assemble code and found it use `objc_msgSend_stret` which means the array is treated as struct. Or if you think I am wrong and you know the truth, you can answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709923/return-fixed-size-array

Comment: @xlc - Sorry Chuck is correct. I hadn't seen your question, which had gone unanswered by all. I've added an answer for you.